# several parameters in the URL

Tags: php, sql, model-view-controller

I'm trying, in a MVC-like arvchitecture (every page has an url"index.php?action=nameofthepage"), to display a personnal page corresponding to every item already displayed in previous page through a while loop(1):
view page 1:

```
 while ($data=$eleves->fetch()) {?>  
            <div class="enseignant">
                <a href="index.php?action=portraitDanciensIndividuel&amp;id=<?=$data['id']?>"> //  this doesn't work
                    <img src="<?php echo $data['photo']?>" alt="" class="photoEnseignant">
                    <h2 style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;"><?= $data['prenom'] .' '. $data['nom']?></h2>
                </a>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
```

view page 2:

```
    <?php
    $data=$stmt->fetch() ?>
        <img src="<?= $data['photo']?>" alt=""class="AfficherEleveIndividuelPhoto">
        <h3 ><?=$data['prenom'] .' '. $data['nom']?></h3>
        <p class="seCultiverTxt">
            <?=nl2br($data['description'])?>
        </p>
```

model page 2:

```
<?php
//PDO etc.
$stmt = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM eleves WHERE id=?');
$stmt->execute(array($_GET['id']));
```

controller page 2

```
function portraitIndividuel() {
    require ('dbConnect.php');
    require ('models/PortraitsDanciensIndividual.php');
    require ('portraitDancienIndividuelV.php');
}
```

router page 2

```
if ($_GET['action'] == 'portraitDanciensIndividuel') {
            portraitIndividuel();
        }
```

here's my question: i'm wondering how to go on another page using the action parameter and also including the id parameter ?

I'm quite new in php!
I already tried many different things
Any clue is welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine parameters using "&". so in your example you would update to the below on the link

```
  <a href="index.php?action=portraitDanciensIndividuel&id=<?php echo $data['id']; ?>">
```

Then when you're processing that info on the page get it like this:

```
if( isset( $_GET['id'] ) && $_GET['id'] !== '' ){
 $id = $_GET['id'];
}

//or same return in shorthand
$id = isset( $_GET['id'] ) && $_GET['id'] !== '' ? $_GET['id'] : 0;
```

NEVER trust any information coming through the url parameter, always double-check for proper data;)